# what is the best way to pass data from mysql to kafka with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, producer

what is the best way to pass data from mysql to kafka produce

I know there is good kafka-connector.
However I wanna use springboot framework. because I need to transform the data and merge with other http result then I want to produce data to kafka.

so is there any good example, github, blog wahtever~?

Comment: Kafka Connect to get the data into Kafka, *then* use Kafka Streams / ksqlDB to process it. Trying to do it all in one place with Spring is generally not how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Camel and the camel-debezium component. An example found in the docs is the [following](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/debezium-mysql-component.html#_message_body). You may use all Camel features to do any kind of transformation or enrichment, before pushing to a Kafka topic. I think that can be a legit choice if the source data in mysql do not represent your source of truth and you need to filter/ transform before pushing to Kafka.

Listen for events:

```
from("debezium-mysql:dbz-test-1?offsetStorageFileName=/usr/offset-file-1.dat&databaseHostName=localhost&databaseUser=debezium&databasePassword=dbz&databaseServerName=my-app-connector&databaseHistoryFileName=/usr/history-file-1.dat")
    .log("Event received from Debezium : ${body}")
    .log("    with this identifier ${headers.CamelDebeziumIdentifier}")
    .log("    with these source metadata ${headers.CamelDebeziumSourceMetadata}")
    .log("    the event occured upon this operation '${headers.CamelDebeziumSourceOperation}'")
    .log("    on this database '${headers.CamelDebeziumSourceMetadata[db]}' and this table '${headers.CamelDebeziumSourceMetadata[table]}'")
    .log("    with the key ${headers.CamelDebeziumKey}")
    .log("    the previous value is ${headers.CamelDebeziumBefore}")
```

[Produce](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/master/examples/camel-example-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/kafka/MessagePublisherClient.java) to Kafka after you read/ transform:

```
.to("kafka:{{topic}}")
```

Also, check out the [Spring boot guide](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/debezium-postgres-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-debezium-mysql-starter</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

An detailed github example that includes Camel transformations is [here](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/camel-component/qa-camel/src/main/java/io/debezium/examples/camel/pipeline/QaDatabaseUserNotifier.java).